# Why is cross posting discouraged?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

Suppose, a question can have two different answers in two sites, is it allowed?

Why is cross posting always discouraged?

Is it for saving the Stack Exchange system memory? 
Or, to avoid Google returns multiple results for the same topic?

Comment: That sounds like an extreme edge case. Can you give some concrete example of such a question please?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd You can ask the same question related to Old Testament(Torah) both in Judaism and Christianity and get different answers or views.

Comment: @Mawia well, the accepted answer in the linked faq says "99.99% of questions people have labeled as being applicable cross-site have been proven to be valid on a single site if written properly and thought through" - if you can come with a question belonging to the 0.01% that can't be proven as valid only on one site, personally I think it's OK to post on both sites. Maybe best post it here first and see what others think though. :)

Comment: Ask on [Judaism.SE] if you're interested in an answer from the perspective of a Jew and/or the Jewish religion. Ask on [Christianity.SE] if you're interested in the answer from the perspective of a Christian and/or the Christian religion. Ask on [Hermeneutics.SE] if you're interested in the answer from a non-religious, biblical exegesis perspective. (I can't believe I had to write that, I thought it would be obvious.)

Comment: That means, it has nothing to do with the memory and Google thing?

Comment: @Cody but is it an "OR" or an "AND"?